# How to reliably deny direct access to PHP file on server?

Tags: php

First of all, let me say that I know there have been a few articles already posted on this manner, but I feel like a lot of them use a method of accessing a HTTP variable from `$_SERVER` like `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` to ensure authentication. But to my understanding, these can a lot of the times be spoofed. Is there no simple way to reliably deny direct access to my PHP api and only allow requests to be made to it from my Angular front-end?

Comment: Not a complete solution, but can you block/deny certain requests via the web server?

Comment: No, there is no simple way. You must authenticate every request.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Well yea, I guess that's my question. How should I go about authenticating every request?

Answer (score -1):

It's going to depend on your webserver.

For example, in Apache, you'd create a .htaccess file, and then add a directive to your main conf file to include the .htaccess for the directory that the .php file lives in. You include files in the subdirectory in the main script, and then those methods in the "protected" file can be called from the primary script.

But, basically, you need to put the script in a subdirectory, and then use the webserver configurations to deny access to web requests for that script.

That's if it's a normal script file.

If, for some reason, you want to restrict access to a data file using PHP, you put this as the first line in the file and name it .php:

```
'; <?php die('Access denied'); ?>
```

Then JSON/data inside the file. It can be read by PHP as a direct call, but will never be read out by the PHP executor.

Comment: The question uses the term "direct" to mean "accessed by the user typing the URL in as opposed to accessed by the JavaScript I supply the user with" and not "accessed by an HTTP client as opposed to accessed from another PHP program".